# Flaw of proof: polynomial ring is integrally closed if the coefficient ring is integrally closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be an integrally closed domain. Then I want to show $R[x]$ is integrally closed.

Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $R$ and if I choose a function $a(x)\in K(x)$ which is integral over $R[x]$, then it is also integral over $K[x]$. Since a UFD is integrally closed, we have $a(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\in K[x]$. So it is enough to show each $a_i\in K$ is contained in $R$.

Since $a(x)$ is integral over $R[x]$, we have an equation $a(x)^m+c_1(x)a(x)^{m-1}+\cdots+c_m(x)=0$. Looking at the zeroth degree term, and since $R$ is integrally closed, we have $a_0\in R$.
Thus if we can show that $a_1\in R$ as well, the remaing $a_i\in R$ by the same method.
Since both $a(x)$ and $a_0$ are integrally closed, their difference $a'(x):=a(x)-a_0=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x$ is integrally closed. Then we have a new equation
\begin{equation} \label{new_eqn}
a'(x)^k+d_1(x)a'(x)^{k-1}+\cdots+d_k(x)=0 \, . \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Here, since $a'(x)$ has no constant term, it is deduced that $d_k(x)$ has no constant term, so a multiple of $x$. So, the equation (\ref{new_eqn}) can be divided by $x$ and we get $a_1\in R$ once more by looking at the constant terms and using the condition that $R$ is integrally closed.

There are somewhat complicated proofs (e.g. [Trouble with proving $A$ is an integrally closed domain $\Rightarrow$ $A[t]$ is integrally closed domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412714/trouble-with-proving-a-is-an-integrally-closed-domain-rightarrow-at-is)) for the same statement, but I don't know why the above proof is not given in any reference. Does this proof has some flaw?

Comment: You say "(1) can be divided by $x$". What happens then?

Comment: I just realized that after writing this article. The eq for $a_1$ is not monic, which involves a power of $x$ in the highest degree coefficient. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I like your approach.  You just need to patch the hole in your proof by showing

> If $f \in K[x]$ is integral over $R[x]$ with lowest nonzero coefficient $f_0$, then $f_0$ is integral over $R$.

Comment: Doesn't the claim in the quote simply follow from evaluating the integral relation at $x=0$?

Comment: Yes, good point. I edited the answer because it was overcomplicating something trivial.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood some part in this, this only works in degree 0 term.

Comment: @lyuinnhe. once we know that $f \in K[x]$ is integral over $R[x]$ and $f_0 \in K$ is integral over $R$, we also get that $f - f_0 \in K[x]$ is integral over $R[x]$ (integral elements are closed under addition and multiplication).  It's easy to check that $(f-f_0)/x$ is also integral over $R[x]$ and then we can proceed by induction.

Comment: @BadamBaplan Why it is easy to check that $(f-f_0)/x$ is integral over $R[x]?$ I don't see why this is even true

Comment: @rowcol you're right, this part is really the meat of the proof, this was a terrible answer from many years ago.

Comment: @rowcol that said, it certainly is true that $fx$ integral implies $f$ integral.  One way to do it is to pick a finite type $\mathbb{Z}$ algebra $R'$ generated by the elements of $R$ that are needed to express the integral dependence for $fx$.   From the integral dependence for $fx$, you can find a polynomial $g \in R'[x]$ such that $(fx)^n g \in R'[x]$ for all $n$.

Comment: @rowcol This implies $f^n g \in R'[x]$ for all $n$, too.  Then $fI \subseteq I$ for the ideal $I$ generated by $f^n g$.  Since $R'$ is Noetherian, $I$ is a finitely generated ideal.  Therefore (using the determinant trick), $f$ is integral over $R'[x]$, and moreover $f$ is integral over $R[x]$.